# How to customize response error message in wso2 api manager 3.2.0?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

How can I change wso2 api manager 3.2.0 response error message from xml to json?And also how can I customize errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/troubleshooting/error-handling/#custom-error-messages) document provides details on how to customize error messages.

You can change the response error message format from `xml` to `json` by changing the `messageType` property from `application/xml` to `application/json` in the xml file